# dnsmasq disabled on Network Manager

Tags: wireless, network-manager, dnsmasq

When I first started using Ubuntu, it would always use dnsmasq. I mean when I would enter 
    `$ nslookup www.bing.com`     

The result would come from 127.0.0.1. But after installing and configuring ap-hotspot, dnsmasq will only work when I have started ap-hotspot. But I need dnsmasq to work when I don't have ap-hotspot started.

How can I make dnsmasq working like it did work on all type of connections before?

Making dnsmasq work is important for me cause it makes modifications on hosts file work.

```
nahin@nahin:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   nahin

141.101.118.195 thepiratebay.se
31.13.79.246 m.facebook.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters    

nahin@nahin:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 208.67.222.222

nahin@nahin:~$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnqsmasq

no-auto-default=**.**.**.**.**.**,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `cat /etc/hosts` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`  to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be a typo if you copied by hand but the line in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` should be `dns=dnsmasq` not `dns=dnqsmasq` that you have reported.

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` file is missing a nameserver line

```
echo "nameserver 127.0.1.1" | sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then reboot

Comment: I have solved this by fixing the error in     /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf